# Blur changing bitmap permanently

Tags: android, bitmap, blur, renderscript

I have a seekbar and on change in seekbar I run this Async task for blurring the bitmap; so, basically when I move seekbar to right bitmap should blur more and when moves to left blur should be less. But when I start moving my seekbar bitmap gets blurred more and more even if I move it to the left, decreasing blur radius. Here as seen in code I never change the "mainBitmap" but when I debug the app, I saw activity.mainBitmap getting changed and thats why when seekbar movement blurs the bitmap progressively.

Any idea what mistake I am doing here.

Thanks in advance!

```
 private final class Blur extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

        activity.showProgressBar();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        Bitmap bitmap = activity.mainBitmap;

        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
        RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(activity);

        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, bitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);
        //Intrinsic Gaussian blur filter
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));

        theIntrinsic.setRadius(params[0]);

        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

        return outputBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap newBit) {

        activity.hideProgressBar();
        activity.mainImage.setImageBitmap(newBit);
    }
```

Comment: I would give a try to something very fast. Try to make a copy of the original  with `Bitmap src = yourOriginal;
Bitmap dst = src.copy(src.getConfig(), src.isMutable);` and check if you are giving by reference the bitmap and changing it without trying to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just passing the `reference` of the `mainBitmap` thats why the `mainBitmap` changes. You should make a copy of it and then blur it.

Instead of

```
Bitmap bitmap = activity.mainBitmap;
```

you should use:

```
Bitmap bitmap = activity.mainBitmap.copy(activity.mainBitmap.getConfig(),true);
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: gj... my comment like 10 mins before her answer. But my fault for not posting an answer instead

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating bitmap again and again in onSeekChange for every value,
This will through OutOfMemoryException

Follow this steps
- Create one fully blurred image
- Add one more image view over your main image and set blurred bitmap over it as an overlay and set its alpha 0 i.e. fully transparent.
- Now when user moves seekbar try to change alpha of the overlayed blurred image.